# Integrating QWT 6.0.1 with Qt Creator/Designer 4.8.0

Tags: qt, qwt

I've installed the Qt SDK version 4.8.0 (to `C:\QtSDK`) on a Windows 7 64-bit machine. I've also installed and successfully compiled QWT 6.0.1 with MSVC2010.
I can use QWT in C++ code by linking to the libraries; however when I try to use the plugin I get an error that I can't seem to find on the Googles.

**My failed plugin error is:**

> The plugin 'C:/QtSDK/QtCreator/bin/designer/qwt_designer_plugin.dll' uses an incompatible Qt library. (4.8.0) [release]

My `QWTbuild.pri` has `CONFIG += debug_and_release` 
**I built the plugin by doing:**

> C:\QtSDK\QWT\qwt-6.0.1\designer > qmake designer.pro 
>   C:\QtSDK\QWT\qwt-6.0.1\designer > nmake release

I then copied the `.dll` generated (`qwt_designer_plugin.dll`) in  `C:\QtSDK\QWT\qwt-6.0.1\designer\plugins\designer` to my plugin path for QtCreator (`C:\QtSDK\QtCreator\bin\designer`)

I've also put the `.dll` and the `.lib` generated in the Qt plugins folder (`C:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.0\msvc2010\plugins\designer`).

I've also linked my libraries in the project file containing the form I'm trying to build.

I'm sure that there's something small I'm missing, but I can't seem to find it. 
 What am I doing wrong here? 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Alexis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Qt plugins should use the same version of Qt or a lower version with the same major number as the application they are loaded in.

Since the Qt Creator currently included in the Qt SDK seems to use Qt 4.7.4, you should probably recompile Qwt for that version of Qt.

Comment: Ok - I did this, and installed QT4.7.4 from the QT SDK. I added qwt to my path and followed [These Instructions](http://www.qtcentre.org/archive/index.php/t-47151.html) including editing the batch file. My Error has changed to:"Cannot load library C:/QtSDK_4.7/QtCreator/bin/designer/qwt_designer_plugin.dll: The specified procedure could not be found." Any more ideas? Thank you again!

Comment: @KittenWhiskers These instruction are for the MinGW compiler. QtCreator is compiled with VC++, so the plugins should be too (you can  also recompile QtCreator with MinGW, but it's not so straightforward either).

Comment: sorry I should have specified - I followed those instructions from about number 12 on, setting the path variables etc. I don't have mingw on my system and everything is compiled with msvc2010. Was there something different I should have done?